# jQuery UI autocomplete error via Web Service/JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I've been trying to get this to work for a few hours now but can't see where I'm going wrong.

I've been checking Firebug for the server response and it retrieves the json data via .asmx web service fine. The only error i have to go off is the one in firebug that's triggered when 2 or more characters are typed in:
**TypeError: c.settings[d].call is not a function**

***jQuery Code Snippet:***

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= txtCustomer.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            async: true,
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../Services/AJAXHandler.asmx/GetCustomers",
                    data: "{'filter':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                            return { 
                                label: item.customerName
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown + " : " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText + " : " + XMLHttpRequest.status;

                        if (XMLHttpRequest.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort")
                        {
                            alert(errorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be brilliant.

Comment: What line in the code is throwing that error?

Comment: its in the jQuery 1.8.2 library file, which i thought was strange.